# Get all $_POST data is okay but error when $_POST['parameterName']?

Tags: php, http, http-post

I try to get a http parameter by using $_POST['rstore_name'] but it keeps showing error:
Notice: Undefined index: rstore_name

Then I try to print all $_POST by foreach loop , it print 'rstore_name' value correctly.

What happened to my $_POST['rstore_name'] command ??

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'action_woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' );
    function action_woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping() {

        $_POST['rstore_name'];

        foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
           echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";
        }

    }
```

[image: form data return from ezship]

Comment: Perhaps it is not the same string byte for byte?

Comment: I don't understand what is byte for byte.... why is so difficult getting a http parameter using php....  ><

Comment: make sure you are doing `$_POST['rstore_name'] ` not `$_POST('rstore_name');`

Comment: I've corrected my post , I'm sure I use $_POST['rstore_name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the most annoying situations to find yourself in. Try print_r with pre-formatting then copy for it that key as it sees it; maybe it has some spaces;

```
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($_POST);
echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: Better to use `var_dump(array_keys($_POST));` as it gives the length as well.

Comment: The command helps to trace down to the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use $_POST['Param']['rstore_name'] instead of $_POST['rstore_name'].

Comment: What is the concept of this command? I tried but didn't work...
It shows : Notice: Undefined index: param in  /var/www/sib-skincare/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code on line 73

Comment: They added that text in the echo `echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";`